# Completly skip rendering of component

Tags: laravel-livewire

How can I set the component to only show if there are videos?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Video;
use Livewire\Component;

class VideosBrowse extends Component
{    
    // Computed Property
    public function getVideosProperty()
    {
        return Video::latest()->paginate(10);
    }

    public function output($errors = null)
    {
        if (!$this->videos || $this->videos->isEmpty()) {
            $this->skipRender();
        }

        return parent::output($errors);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.videos.browse');
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div id="videos-browse">
    @if ($this->videos && $this->videos->isNotEmpty())
        Videos
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: Make it an empty view if there are no records

Comment: Returning empty view causes the issues with 'Livewire requires that there be only one HTML element at the root of a components blade view'.

Comment: Trying to find a way of complelety skipping the rendering all together without the need of empty elements in the DOM.

Comment: Then you have to do that where you render the component, ie the parent component

Comment: The error you're getting is because you do not have a singular root element in your Livewire component. It would help if you shared your blade file.

Comment: @Yinci I'm asking if there's a way to skip the blade rendering completely. 
E.g if no "videos" are found simple don't bother with view rendering anything.

Comment: @JohnMagnolia You're already using `skipRender`, that's all you need.

Comment: @Yinci Yes it calls that but it doesn't make any difference - the view is still rendered. Do I need to call it from a different method?

Comment: `skipRender` does exactly what it says it does; it skips the next render cycle. So if your goal is to _not render anything at all_ you require a different approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to run `skipRender()` on `render`

```
public function render() {

     if (!$this->videos || $this->videos->isEmpty()) {
         $this->skipRender();
     }

    return view('livewire.videos.browse');
}
```